# Summernote not showing me source code it is showing code output

Tags: javascript, jquery, summernote

I have used this script for summernote

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
      $('.summernote').summernote({
        height: 200
      });

      $('form').on('submit', function (e) {
        alert($('.summernote').code());
      });
    });
  </script>
```

Now here the problem is if I text this bellow code

```
<html>
    <head><title>global scope post</title></head>
    <body>
        <form action="" method="post">
            Name:<input type="text" name="name">
            <button>Submit</button>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is giving me output of the the code like as below image.

[image]

How I will define code in summernote ? Here I have tried code tag but the result is same.

Comment: You have used `$('.summernote')`, but I don't see a class `summernote` being used anywhere in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
<input type="text" name="name" class="summernote" />
```

In place of:

```
<input type="text" name="name">
```

Comment: Here the problem is source code show in output.For example in stakoverflow if I select the code and press clr+k it will make code.In output that will show me source code.This option how can I see by summernote ? Here bellow code that I have used in input in summernote editor but it showing me the output of the html code not showing me source code.